# Shared Documentation in GitLab over several repos

Tags: gitlab, markdown, documentation

We have serveral microservices for which we have artifacts in GitLab. (like for example helm chart, valuesfiles...)

For better documentation we have a deployment.png that shows the deployment path. Like where we get the images from and how we import our helm-charts and how to access the Openshift-Cluster from the jumphost.

This diagram should be included in every microservice repo so that everybody who has to deal with the microservices sees the diagram.

Now I don't want to have duplicated code and don't want to check in and take care for the deployment.png and the Text below it in every microservice.

Is there a good solution for that usecase?

We thought about having an extra documentation-repo and pulling in the relevant Readme with the image as a link into the respective microservice-readmes in each microservice-repo...

Any idea or best practice?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to have a way to reference the same image and text files for multiple documents. All you have to know is the url location to your image and it can be referenced/embedded.
For example, `![deployment img](gitlab.com/.../...)`
A statement such as this will embed a file or image in a markdown file. If we remove the `!` from the front, it simply links to the file location as a hyperlink.
The same strategy goes for the text file.